# Perl Data Dumper Specifiers Explanation

Tags: perl, data-dumper

Observing the output of Data::Dumper, the specifiers (`$VAR1`, `""`, `;`) are not explained in the CPAN documentation.

1. What is the purpose for the `$VAR1`?
2. What is the purpose for the semicolon?
3. What is the purpose for the quotations?

Here is my output:

```
$VAR1 = "Snow";
$VAR1 = "Rain";
$VAR1 = "Sunny";
$VAR1 = "";
```

Comment: They're explained [right at the beginning of the documentation](https://perldoc.pl/Data::Dumper#DESCRIPTION).

Comment: Note that you can change the name of the variable used by setting `$Data::Dumper::Varname` (defaults to VAR), and remove those variables and semicolons entirely by setting `$Data::Dumper::Terse` to 1, if you don't care about being able to string-eval the result (most people don't).

Comment: @Grinnz  this is the type of information I was looking for when talking about the data dumper. Many people want to score this question down,  but they really don't understand exactly the data dumper module.

Comment: @Grinnz another point I asked this question to get more a practitioner point-of-view when using this module.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you have an array:

```
my @arr = ('Snow','Rain','Sunny');
print Dumper(@arr);
```

When you pass the array, Dumper thinks you passed 3 separate variables. That is why you get:

```
$VAR1 = 'Snow';
$VAR2 = 'Rain';
$VAR3 = 'Sunny';
```

In order to see the array as data structure, you need to pass the reference to the array:

```
print Dumper(\@arr);
```

This will produce:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Snow',
          'Rain',
          'Sunny'
        ];
```

The output says that you passed the reference to array with 3 elements.

Comment: OP's output says `$VAR1` everywhere, indicating that it's from multiple `Dumper` calls.

Answer (score 3):

The specifiers are described in the second paragraph of the DESCRIPTION:

> The return value can be "eval"ed to get back an identical copy of the
>       original reference structure.

So, you can take the string returned by Dumper and run

```
my $x = eval $dumped_string;
```